# Android thread.join() thread force closes when app started again

Tags: android, multithreading, surfaceview, java-threads, android-homebutton

I have a problem with my app. I have a SurfaceHolder for drawing onto a canvas. 
Under the surfaceCreated method, I call `thread.start()`;

Under the surfaceDestroyed method, I call `thread.join()`;

I run my app and press the home key, whoch in turn invokes the `surfaceDestroyed` method.

The problem is that I get a thread already started exception when I subsequently try and run my app again. Why is this? I am even testing to see if the thread is already running using `isAlive()`. Do I need to replace the `thread.join` line with a `thread.wait`?

If so, how can I resume the thread instead of starting it again in `surfaceCreated`?

Answer (score 1):

First - the [`wait`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29) method will not cause the thread to hang.
Second - [`join`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) waits for the thread to die.
Third - I would consider creating a new thread, and not trying to run the same one.